# 写真のアルバム名の一覧を取得ができない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

現在Swiftにて、写真フォルダ内のアルバム名の一覧を取得しようとしています。
ただうまくいかず、ご教授いただきたく、ご質問させていただきました。

下記のコードだと、`album.localizedTitle`に

```
Argument type 'String?!' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
```

というエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
class readPhotoAlbum {

    static var albumList: NSMutableArray!

    static func createAlbumList(){

        let list = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options:nil)

        list.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (album, index, isStop) -> Void in
            albumList.addObject(album.localizedTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

下記のように`album.localizedTitle!!`とするとそのエラーは表示されなくなりますが、
ビルド途中で

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optical value
```

というメッセージと共に落ちてしまいます。
breakpointを設定してみてみると`albumList.addObject(album.localizedTitle!!)`の行で止まってしまっているようです。

```
class readPhotoAlbum {

    static var albumList: NSMutableArray!

    static func createAlbumList(){

        let list = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options:nil)

        list.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (album, index, isStop) -> Void in
            albumList.addObject(album.localizedTitle!!)
        }
    }
}
```

なお、私の環境はXcode 7.0.1,端末はiOS9.0.2になります。

ちなみに、上記のコードを書く際に参考にさせていただいているのは、[このページ](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/4-photokit/003-arubamuwo-jian-suosuru)です。

よろしくお願い致します。

※追記
kishikawaさん、Harawoさんのコメントを参考に、
下記に修正したところ、無事アルバム名の取得をすることができました。
ありがとうございます。

```
class readPhotoAlbum {

    static var albumList = NSMutableArray()

    static func createAlbumList(){

        let list = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, options:nil)

        list.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (album, index, isStop) -> Void in
            if let album = album as? PHCollection { // PHCollectionにキャスト
                if let localizedTitle = album.localizedTitle { // localizedTitleはnilの可能性がある
                    albumList.addObject(localizedTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず`Argument type 'String?!' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'`というエラーについてですが、`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock()`メソッドの引数は`AnyObject, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>`なので、`album`オブジェクトの型は`AnyObject`として渡されます。そのため、アルバムのオブジェクトとして扱うためにはその型`PHCollection`にキャストする必要があります。

そして、`localizedTitle`は`nil`の可能性があるので、例えばOptional Bindingなどを使って`nil`ではないことを保証してから使う必要があります。

```
list.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (album, index, isStop) -> Void in
    if let album = album as? PHCollection { // PHCollectionにキャスト
        if let localizedTitle = album.localizedTitle { // localizedTitleはnilの可能性がある
            albumList.addObject(album.localizedTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static var albumList: NSMutableArray!
```

このプロパティ`albumList`の宣言ですと、初期値は`nil`になるので、`addObject()`メソッドを送ると、エラーが発生します。

```
static var albumList = NSMutableArray()
```

このように宣言とともに要素が空の`NSMutableArray`を生成するといいでしょう。